# Billing at google cloud

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-billing

Do we really need to enable google billing?
I thought it is free to use?
Im using google cloud for current location and retrieve data from location

Answer (score 1):

Google cloud have a trial account that gives you $ 200 in google cloud. You can spend this money on various functions. You can only access the map for free without any features.

Answer (score -1):

Google Maps is the services of Google and Google migrating their services of Google Maps into the Google Cloud Platform for easy of use.

Regarding the Billing, Google offers Google Map pay as you go, model and Google Map have different services so, they calculate the billing based on the Request from your API keypoint.